# Download spedific tab of google sheet in R

Tags: r, google-sheets, googlesheets4

I'm trying to download a specific tab from a google sheet to R,  after trying gsheet package I only get the first tab, no matter how I change the sheetid.

I also try the library googlesheets4 to identify the sheet id but I got empty result, what did I do wrong?  is there other way to complete this simple task? Thanks!

```
url <- 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2QrNMz8pIbYEKzMJL7Uh2dtThOJa2j1sSMwiDo5Gz4/htmlview?pru=AAABc95C0MI*0Y0sH44yYwVlu_QuDo_X3g#'
 ridoc <- gsheet2tbl(url)
 ridoc2 <- gsheet2tbl(url,sheetid = 2)

sheets_auth()
theSheets <- sheets_find()
theSheets
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the function `read_sheet()` from googlesheets4?

```
df <- read_sheet(url, sheetname)
```

where sheetname is the name of the sheet (in string) you want to read.

If you want to read all sheets:

```
sheets_names <- sheet_names(url)
list_1 <- lapply(sheets_names, function (x) read_sheet(url, x))
```